# How to verify form submitted from the same server witout using HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: forms, submit

I have this form on my site, i want to prevent from users to submit the form from local copy. or submit the form from other domain (Cross Site Scripting).

the HTTP_REFERER is not trusted because its easy to fake.

I have idea to verify where the form was submitted, by calling to the server just before submit the info. but i am not so sure if its good idea.
Thank 
ilanko

Answer (score 0):

That's called [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and is usually solved by having a hidden `input` inside a form. Value of the said `input` is assigned on the server side and is stored in a session. Upon form submit these two values are compared and form submission continues only if they're equal.

Comment: Thank, but the server session timeout allow enough time to view source and save the form, and finally submit local copy of it, including the valid hidden input.

Comment: @ilanko That's impossible. When you submit a page locally, you'll get a whole new session.